# I have a tabulator table, align

Tags: tabulator

I have a tabulator table, with three columns that are align to the right, but if the "`value`" in the first column is "`xxx`",  the value in the cell need to be change to be align to the left, is this possible?

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example_table", {

  layout: "fitDataFill",


  placeholder: "No Data Set Found",

  columns: [{
      title: "name",
      field: "name",
      sorter: "string",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "Filter Exception Name",
      formatter: "label",
      width: 70,
    },

    {
      title: "name value",
      field: "namevalue",
      sorter: "string",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "Filter Exception Policy Data",
      headerFilter: "input",
      formatter: celldataswith,
      align: "right"
    },
    {
      title: "permited value",
      field: "permitedvalue",
      sorter: "string",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "Filter Exception Criteria",
      headerFilter: "input",
      formatter: celldataswith,
      align: "right"
    },
    {
      title: "breach value",
      field: "breachvalue",
      sorter: "string",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "Filter Exception Breach",
      headerFilter: "input",
      formatter: celldataswith,
      align: "right"
    }


  ],
  rowFormatter: function(row, cell) {
    //row - row component

    var dataExceptionName = row.getData().Name;

    if (dataExceptionName == "xxx") {
      row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#A6A6DF";

      **cell.getData().namevalue.style.align = "left";
      cell.getData().permitedvalue.style.align = "left";
      cell.getData().breachvalue.style.align = "left";**
    }
  },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom cell formatter to achieve this, define the formatter outside the table, then reference it in the column definitions

```
//define formatter
var alignFormatter = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    var data = cell.getData();

    if(data.name === "xxx"){
        cell.getElement().style.align = "left";
    }else{
        cell.getElement().style.align = "right";
    }
}

//column definition
{title: "name value", field: "namevalue", formatter:alignFormatter},
```